# Is it possible to detect whether a request is truly from localhost or is forged to "look like" from localhost in application layer?

Tags: networking, firewall

Based on my understanding, there are some tools that can send a request from an IP address and make the request appear to servers like from another IP address, including from localhost.

Now I have a server with a specific API that only allows requests from localhost but has some other APIs that allow requests from the internet.

The only way I can think of is to set the firewall so that any incoming packet will be blocked if the destination contains the "localhost only" API name. However this forces me to design my server in such a way that no other APIs has a substring name of the "localhost only" API. This means the "localhost only" API cannot have a short name and can be a risk if I forget this fact and/or the code is maintained by other people in the future.

Ideally, I want to distinguish whether a request truly comes from localhost at application layer and if not so block further processing of the API.

What I want to know is whether this is possible or not, in terms of networking.